# Jtoolbarhelper CANCEL button is not working

Tags: joomla3.0

I am new to joomla component. My cancel and save button are not working in admin domain of joomla. In my view.html.php file I have called Jtoolbarhelper as:

```
protected function addToolBar()
    {
        //$state = $this->get('State');
        JToolBarHelper::title(JText::_('Ankur Blogs'));
        JToolBarHelper::save('blogs.save');
        JToolBarHelper::cancel('blogs.cancel');
```

blogs is controller and cancel is method inside the controller.

And in blogs, I have written:

```
public function cancel()
    {
    //echo 'aa';exit;
    $this->setredirect(JRoute::_('http://localhost/cms/administrator/index.php?option=com_myblog&view=viewblog', false));
  //parent::display();
    }
```

When I am clicking on cancel button, it is saying,

```
"Error and component not found".
```

And when I am seeing into the console of browser, it is showing

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/cms/administrator/index.php?option=com_myblog"
```

please do help me.......``

Comment: Please any one can HELP?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem. In my case my template was not created properly. The `adminForm` element in the template must have `method="POST"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late for an answer but your form must have the following fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_myblog" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
```

Replace the com_myblog with the name of your component.